# Is there any way that I could upload an image on the page to the server?

Tags: php

I have this code that has an image tag. The img src is equal to `"https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user_id; ?>/picture"`. Is there anyway that I could get that image file and upload it to my server using the `move_uploaded_image` function with php?

Answer (score 1):

No, `move_uploaded_image` moves files that were uploaded in a POST request.

If you want to get an image from a URL you need to make an HTTP request for it, e.g. via [cURL](http://php.net/curl).

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP's `imagecreate` and `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`, you can create a blank image, get the image from the remote URL, then replace the blank image you created.

Similar to,

```
    // Create a blank image 
    $imPath = "path/to/your/desired/image.jpg";
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(180, 151);
    imagejpeg($im,$imPath);

    // Download their fb image
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $user['username'] . '/picture?type=large';
    $bytes = file_put_contents($imPath, file_get_contents($url));
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no function like move_uploaded_image . correct function is move_uploaded_file.

no. you can not get image file by this function . 
first argument of this function is temp file name which is uploaded through Input type = file.

and another argument is the location where you want to put file....

you should refer $_FILES of php manual for more information....
http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php